# How to implement default value of steps in array

Tags: javascript

I have some default steps which my order goes through

```
const defaultSteps = [
'In preparation',
'Order taken from courier',
'Order is on its way',
'Order delivered to customer',
'Partner declined order'
];
```

I get from backend history array which contains date when status is changed and name of status

```
history: [ { status_name: "In preparation", status_id: "62a74ac2fc767ef024f031cd", date_updated: 2022-06-14T20:29:51.784+00:00 }, { status_name: "Order taken from courier", status_id: "62a74ac2fc767ef024f031cd", date_updated: 2022-06-14T20:29:51.784+00:00 } ]
```

I want to create new array that checks if that step is in history, push that element from history with date field to array else push's element from defaultSteps

Comment: Do you want to have a new array with the statuses that have additional information replaced by the corresponding object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, you can loop through both arrays with `Array.forEach()` and push the elements into the new array:

```js
const defaultSteps = [
'In preparation',
'Order taken from courier',
'Order is on its way',
'Order delivered to customer',
'Partner declined order'
];

const result = []

const history = [ { status_name: "In preparation", status_id: "62a74ac2fc767ef024f031cd", date_updated: "2022-06-14T20:29:51.784+00:00" }, { status_name: "Order taken from courier", status_id: "62a74ac2fc767ef024f031cd", date_updated: "2022-06-14T20:29:51.784+00:00" } ]

defaultSteps.forEach(str => {
    let hasMatch = false
    history.forEach(obj => {
        if(str === obj.status_name) {
            result.push(obj)
            hasMatch = true
        }
    })
    if(!hasMatch) {
        result.push(str)
    }
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly you can do this:

```
const data = defaultSteps.map(item => history.find(i => i.status_name === item) || item)
```

data is your new array